# Run asp.net core service on server 2008

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to run web api service on server 2008 rc2,
the service was built with asp.net core.

Windows throws this exceptions:

> Application: WebAPI.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.TypeInitializationException Stack:    at
>   System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener..ctor(System.String)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildHostingServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()    at
>   WebAPI.Program.Main(System.String[])
>
> Faulting application name: WebAPI.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp:
>   0x585bb55a Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.2.9200.16864, time stamp: 0x531d34d8 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x0000000000047b8c Faulting process id: 0x1334 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d25c444e9f7598 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Users\administrator.SITE\Desktop\win7-x64\WebAPI.exe Faulting
>   module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   8d569e16-c837-11e6-93f5-0050568b4414 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Is anybody have an idea what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem, could you find a solution?